# How can i clone from git for try to testing in my android?

Tags: android, git, clone

I want to try to run this airbnb clone app in my android studio 
but the problem is it's not working in my android studio

https://github.com/mdy0501/Airbnb

It just show in my console

!-- console --!

```
7:01:05: Executing task...


> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 5.1.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
7:01:05: Task execution finished.
```

I want to know how to run that app in my android AVD

Is that possbile..? running in my android studio that app ? 
i can't find how to run...

Comment: Push the run button at the top of android studio. It's a green triangle, you can't miss it.

Comment: I know the run button... but it can't run

Comment: What are the words in the box to the left of the green button? It should say `app`

Comment: After i clone from git 
and click the button 'run' it show just 'Edit Configuration'

Comment: You can try this my solution

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the repository you have cloned is Android project
2. Before `Run` the demo you should sync your project

   [image]

   [image]

   You will see a lot output in the `Build` window at the Android Studio bottom.

   [image]
3. Project sync successfully the `Run` button will look like this.

   [image]

   If `sync` operation failed it means project did not configure correctly just try to fix the error according to the `sync` output.

Comment: I already try to like u but it's not working that app
I guess there is some reason why didn't run in android that app right away 
but i don't know... why....